# JS handing format base64 string value to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm using Blazor as a web application and im using a js function to get the value of converted base64 file to my C# app.
the value that thr func returns is the base64 uri string `'data:application/pdf;base64....'`

Currently I'm having trouble with getting the previous scanned file base64 string to my C# app and not the current file im requesting the main problem is the Promise returned value of the function call it first preforme `getItem()` before `setItem()`

```
function getPDFFile() {
    const element = document.getElementById("report");

     var file = html2pdf().set({
        html2canvas: {
            onclone: (element) => {
                const svgElements = Array.from(element.querySelectorAll('svg'));
                svgElements.forEach(s => {
                    const bBox = s.getBBox();
                    s.setAttribute("x", bBox.x);
                    //s.setAttribute("y", bBox.y);
                    s.setAttribute("width", bBox.width);
                    s.setAttribute("height", s.scrollHeight);
                });
            }
        },
        scale: 4,
        /*pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all', after: '#otd_table' },*/
        jsPDF: { format: 'a3' }
    }).from(element).toPdf().output("datauristring");

    file.output("datauristring").then(function (pdf, item) {
        localStorage.setItem("base64", pdf);
    });
    
    var x = localStorage.getItem("base64");
    x = x.replace('data:application/pdf;base64,', '')
    return x;
}
```

Comment: *I'm having trouble* - that's not a real problem description and what you posted is not a real question. What is the code above supposed to do? What result do you expect and what result do you get actually? If you get any errors, include them as well. Please read [ask] and edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Edited Hope its clear now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out my problem because `then` holds my previous value of base64 string so i added `await` and `async` and it works fine, now i wait till setItem() before i do getItem()

```
async function getPDFFile() {

    const element = document.getElementById("report");

     var file = html2pdf().set({
        html2canvas: {
            onclone: (element) => {
                const svgElements = Array.from(element.querySelectorAll('svg'));
                svgElements.forEach(s => {
                    const bBox = s.getBBox();
                    s.setAttribute("x", bBox.x);
                    //s.setAttribute("y", bBox.y);
                    s.setAttribute("width", bBox.width);
                    s.setAttribute("height", s.scrollHeight);
                });
            }
        },
        scale: 4,
        /*pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all', after: '#otd_table' },*/
        jsPDF: { format: 'a3' }
    }).from(element).toPdf().output("datauristring");

    await file.output("datauristring").then(function (pdf, item) {
        localStorage.setItem("base64", pdf);
    });
 
    var x = localStorage.getItem("base64");
    x = x.replace('data:application/pdf;base64,', '')
    return x;
}
```